# How to get user id using OneDrive service in uwp community toolkit

Tags: c#, uwp, onedrive, windows-community-toolkit

I'm using OneDrive service in uwp community toolkit.
I can got all folders, but don't know how t get user id(of course not email address, I mean a unique id that represent the user).

Who can help, thanks.

```
if (await OneDriveService.Instance.LoginAsync())
{
    _appFolder = await OneDriveService.Instance.AppRootFolderAsync();
    ShowBusy(false);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When debuging, I find a user id, located in OneDriveService.Instance ---- Provider ---- AuthenticationProvider ---- CurrentAccountSession ---- UserId, but don't know how to get it

If you check the community toolkit source code, you will find that `CurrentAccountSession` is belong to MsaAuthenticationProvider class. And this class is in [Microsoft.OneDrive.Sdk.Authentication](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-dotnet-msa-auth-adapter/blob/master/src/OneDrive.Sdk.Authentication.Common/MsaAuthenticationProvider.cs#L278) namespace. If you want to get the `UserId`, you would need to change community toolkit's source code and compile a custom version by yourself.

For example, in [OneDriveService.cs](https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/blob/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Services/Services/OneDrive/OneDriveService.cs#L193), you could convert `_accountProvider` to `MsaAuthenticationProvider` like this `(_accountProvider as MsaAuthenticationProvider).CurrentAccountSession.UserId`.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to get user identifier. You could implement it and then raise a PR for it or you could raise an issue and see how that goes.

https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/issues

Comment: When debuging, I find a user id, located in OneDriveService.Instance ---- Provider ---- AuthenticationProvider ---- CurrentAccountSession ---- UserId, but don't know how to get it

Comment: @Vincent If you check the community toolkit source code, you will find that `CurrentAccountSession ` is belong to MsaAuthenticationProvider class. And this class is in [Microsoft.OneDrive.Sdk.Authentication](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-dotnet-msa-auth-adapter/blob/master/src/OneDrive.Sdk.Authentication.Common/MsaAuthenticationProvider.cs#L278) namespace. If you want to get the `UserId`, you would need to change community toolkit's source code and compile a custom version by yourself.

Comment: For example, in [OneDriveService.cs](https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/blob/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Services/Services/OneDrive/OneDriveService.cs#L193), you could convert `_accountProvider ` to `MsaAuthenticationProvider` like this `(_accountProvider as MsaAuthenticationProvider).CurrentAccountSession.UserId`

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT I used in my code, it works. Thanks.                    string userId = (OneDriveService.Instance.Provider.AuthenticationProvider as MsaAuthenticationProvide).CurrentAccountSession.UserId;